# angularjs inheriting scope in nested directives

Tags: angularjs

example in: http://jsfiddle.net/avowkind/PS8UT/

I want a nested child directive to get its data from its wrapping parent directive if present, otherwise from the outer controller.

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <parent index="1">
        <child></child>
    </parent>
    <parent index="2">
        <child></child>
    </parent>
     <h1>No Parent</h1>
    <child></child>
</div>
<hr>
```

Desired output

```
Parent 1
  Child of parent 1
Parent 2
  Child of parent 2
No Parent
  Child of parent 0
```

Currently my child object only sees the outer controller value:

Actual output

```
Parent 1
  Child of parent 0
Parent 2
  Child of parent 0
No Parent
  Child of parent 0
```

This is the simple version; in reality the outer directives get data from a server that is formatted by the nested child so what is communicated is a complex object not a simple string. 
Furthermore the child is a visualisation that will work on different data sets so the outer parent directive is not always the same type.

More generally the pattern I am trying to get here is to have separate directives for populating the model and viewing it. so a more realistic usage would be

```
<temperature-for city="Auckland">
   <plot/>
   <analysis/>
</temperature-for>

<humidity-for city="Hamilton">
   <plot/>
   <analysis/>
</temperature-for>


<test-data>
   <plot/>
</test-data>
```

Comment: from the documentation: "What does this transclude option do, exactly? transclude makes the contents of a directive with this option have access to the scope outside of the directive rather than inside." try using `?^` in the `require` option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A different approach which I personally have had great success using is to define the plot and analysis directives as isolate scopes, and then two-way bind the required input.

This way the directive are completely standalone components, with a *explicit, defined interface*. I personally made a plotting directive like this:

```
<plot data="countries['Auckland'].plot.data" options="countries['Auckland'].plot.options" legend="external" zoom="xy"></plot>

Scope would look like:
scope: {
    data: '=',
    options: '=',
    zoom: '@?',  // '?' indicates optional
    legend: '@?',
}
```

This way there's no confusion what data is required for this component to work, and you can write documentation inside the directive for the desired input attributes.

All in all, this is a pattern which works very well for a large portion of use cases in AngularJS, i.e. whenever there is a case for reusability.

Edit:
Just wanted to add to that: Looking at your HTML, there's absolutely no indication what those directives use, they could depend on anything (e.g. do they get all the data from a service? or do they depend on a parent scope? If so, what scope?)

Comment: This is the approach I adopted. Although it doesn't meet my original spec I accept the value of placing the shared model in the common parent space and having both directives be told what data to use.
I was basically using the nesting to avoid putting the model in the base scope and having to name it twice in the element attributes.  This pattern is closer to having inputs and outputs in different locations on the page except that the input is a hidden field that just gets some data.

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple different ways to do this but assuming that you truly want to use the parent scopes here is a solution to go along with your fiddle.

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

function MyCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.index = 0;
}

myApp.directive('parent', function () {
  return {
    transclude: true,
    scope: {
      index: '='
    },
    restrict: 'EA',
    template: '<h2>Parent {{ index }}</h2>',
    compile: function(tE, tA, transcludeFn) {
      return function (scope, elem, attrs) {
        elem.append(transcludeFn(scope)[1]);
      };
    }
  }
});

myApp.directive('child', function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'EA',
    scope: false,
    template: '<p>Child of parent {{ index }}</p>'
  }
});
```

You can see a fork of your fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/JuBvY/).

The idea is that by getting rid of the ngTranscludeDirective and manually creating the transclusion, you can link the transclusion with the scope of your choosing. Then you can append the result where ever you like in the element resulting from your directive's compilation.

The other main point is to make sure the child directive doesn't create a scope (at all, whether an isolate scope, transcluded scope, or new scope).

I think this will give you the results you're asking for.

**NOTE:** Study your scopes well, because tweaking these behaviors can have unexpected results.

For example, if you add a linking function to the child directive and it sets index to 5:

```js
link: function(scope) {
  scope.index = 5;
}
```

this will not affect `scope.items` for children nested in the parent. However it WILL affect the an external parent scope (in this case MyCtrl's scope). Any directive not inside a parent directive will just keep altering the MyCtrl index.

However if you add a new property to scope in the child link function:

```js
link: function(scope) {
  scope.somethingElse = foo;
}
```

`scope.somethingElse` will be available on the parent scope whether nested in a parent directive or not.

Comment: This answer is correct as it shows exactly how to get the requested pattern. However I am reluctant to manipulate the transclude scope directly thanks to the possible side effects.

Comment: Thanks, and I completely understand @avowkind. Many times not creating a child scope in a given situation can cause the biggest headaches too.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to transclude and fine grain it according to your parent directive scope, you can't do it using the `ng-transclude` directive: http://jsfiddle.net/PS8UT/2/

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.index = 0;
}

myApp.directive('parent', function ($compile) {
    return {
        scope: {
            index: '@'
        },
        restrict: 'EA',
        transclude: true,
        template: '<h2>Parent {{ index }}</h2>',
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs, ctrl, transclude) {
            transclude(scope, function(clone, s){
                elem.append($compile(clone)(s)); // basically you need to reassign the inner child scope to your current isolated scope
            });
        }
    }
});

myApp.directive('child', function () {
    return {
        //scope: true, // no need to create another scope since you want to use the parent
        // scope: { }, // no index printed
        restrict: 'EA',
        template: '<p>Child of parent {{ index }}</p>'
    }
});
```

Usually, when you are dealing with templates and transclusion, needing parent inheritage, is a pain. `ng-transclude` won't use your immediate parent scope as the parent, it usually use your controller scope. It's stated in angular docs [$compile docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24compile):

> transclude
>   compile the content of the element and make it available to the
>   directive.  Typically used with ngTransclude. The advantage of
>   transclusion is that the linking  function receives a transclusion
>   function which is pre-bound to the correct scope. In a  typical setup
>   the widget creates an isolate scope, **but the transclusion is not a
>   child,  but a sibling of the isolate scope**. This makes it possible for
>   the widget to have private  state, and the **transclusion to be bound to
>   the parent (pre-isolate) scope**.